# C++: How many times copy ctor may be called when element is added to the std::set/map or std::unordered_set/map

Tags: c++, std

It is pretty clear that in most of `std::set<T>` implementations insertion of an element causes just one call of the copy ctor of the `T` class. But theoretically it is possible that data structure is implemented in some weird way and up to `c * log N` elements of the set are getting copied for some reasons (during the single insertion).

So my question is: does C++ standard put any constraints on that? If not, how can I sleep well knowing that code like one below can just start taking few years to run with the new version of gcc:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> myMap;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    myMap[rand()][rand()] = rand();
}
```

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee you that `int main(){}` will take less than 1000000 years so in no event you can sleep well.

Answer (score 0):

23.2.4 paragraph 9 specifies:

> The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container,
>   and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

So inserting into a `std::map` cannot move or copy any elements other than the element being inserted.

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't disallow to copy them somewhere, use somehow, and remove copies after that. Right?

Comment: @anxieux: What would be the point of such a copy?  Since references must remain valid, and those references can be used to change values in the map, the relevant values in the map must remain at the same address.

Comment: Yes, that's not very likely... But there is a dumb purist question: does standard forbid library to mine bitcoins while inserting elements to the std::set?